# regex - how to create a regular expression in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm tying to validate a url but not the full url. I want to check if the string contains `com` or `co.uk` and then has `/` and then it has any characters after the /. I'm not bothered with what it starts on ends with. so this would be a match `co.uk/fewfwe` or `com/Grege`

This is what I have so far:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SavePage').click(function (event) {
        var regex = '/com|co\.uk\/[a-zA-Z]/';
        var val = $('#URL').val();
        if (val.match(regex) == null) {
            alert('test');
            event.preventDefault();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to group `com|co\.uk` like this: `/(com|co\.uk)\/[a-zA-Z]/`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight you need to add `+` after the char class.

Comment: So I do. Unfortunately, it seems the edit period for that comment is past.

Comment: For future reference, the quotes around the regex are unnecessary, and actually cause a string to regex conversion when you use `.match(regex)`. In JS, regex literals are delimited by `/` (so yours would be `var regex = /com|co\.uk\/[a-zA-Z]/;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex. It would allow any character  except the `\n` character after the last `/`.

```
(?:com|co\.uk)\/.+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM3aF5/5)

Try the below regex only if you want to allow  alphabets after the last `/` symbol.

```
(?:com|co\.uk)\/[A-Za-z]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM3aF5/6)

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your regex inside a string when it should be a RegExp literal.

Change

```
var regex = '/com|co\.uk\/[a-zA-Z]/';
```

to

```
var regex = /com|co\.uk\/[a-zA-Z]/;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is a combination of **Ben**'s and **Avinash Raj**'s answers. You need to make both changes for this to work, and neither will be enough on its own. I also suggest starting with `\.`, to require a dot before `com` or `co.uk`.

```
var regex = /\.(?:com|co\.uk)\/[a-z]/i;
```

Important: This will only require that the `.com/` or `.co.uk/` is followed by at least one letter. It doesn't require only letters, only that the first thing after the `/` is a letter. This seems like an odd requirement, and probably isn't what you're trying to do.

You don't need a `+` on the end for your example code to work, but the real-world version *may* need it. Some possible variations:

- `var regex = /\.(?:com|co\.uk)\/./i;` - Allows any character after the forward slash
- `var regex = /\.(?:com|co\.uk)\/[a-z]+$/i;` - Allows only letters after the forward slash
- `var regex = /\.(?:com|co\.uk)\/[\w?&%=-]+$/i;` - Will match most URIs
- `var regex = /\S+\.(?:com|co\.uk)\/\S+$/i;` - Will match the whole URI as long as there's no whitespace.

There are a lot of possible variations here, and the correct one is going to depend on the specifics of your situation.